# SharedPreferences - apply() vs. commit()

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I know the difference between apply and commit.
In my case I would like to use `commit()`, but android suggests me to use `apply()` because it runs in background and doesn't block the main thread.

Does something like this work if I use apply or is it possible that apply did not update it before calling?

```
editor.putBoolean("TEST", true)
editor.apply()

if (preferences.getBoolean("TEST")) {
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would expect it to work, as in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) it states:

> `apply()` commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures.

As you're accessing the same preferences object (is a singleton) you should see a consistent view at all times.

Comment: so why is there a function like "commit()"?

Comment: commit is useful if you need to know if the write was successful or not. If you don't use that information, always use apply

Comment: `commit()` was present in the original API level 1, `apply()` was introduced in API level 9. `commit()` returns `true` if the write to disk operation succeeded, while with `apply()` you have to hope for the best.

Comment: Very informatif comment. Thanks @Tim

Answer (score 4):

`apply()` writes to a temporary `Map` that is later written asynchronously to disk.
If you immediately use methods like `getBoolean()` in your case, it will first lookup if there is a value for this key in the temporary `Map` and returns it.

Check the source code of [SharedPreferencesImpl](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java) to see exactly how it's working.